# Why isn't the optimizer using my unique filtered index?

Tags: sql-server

Sample schema:

```
create table dbo.Person (
    ID int identity(1,1) not null
        constraint PK_Person primary key,
    UserName nvarchar(50) null,
    EncryptedPassword nvarchar(100) null
)
create index IX_Person_Login
    on dbo.Person (UserName, EncryptedPassword)
    include (/* other columns */)
create unique index IX_Person_UserName
    on dbo.Person (UserName)
    where (UserName is not null)
```

So now, if I do a lookup of ID by UserName, I would expect that the smaller, more selective index would be chosen by the optimizer. IX_Person_UserName should also be covering because ID is the clustering key (and the resulting plans do bear this out, but that's not the point of the question).

```
select ID
from dbo.Person
where UserName = @UserName
and UserName is not null
```

Yet instead, the optimizer chooses to perform an INDEX SEEK on IX_Person_Login, which is not unique, has more columns in the key, and whose leaf nodes are much larger. If I force the use of IX_Person_UserName, the estimated costs are the same. In both cases the estimated row counts are over 100 but the actual row count is 1. I tried updating statistics but that didn't make any difference in the chosen plan or estimated row counts either. Is it because SQL Server's plan is accounting for the possibility that @UserName might be null? Even if I put a literal non-null string value in the query, it still does not use the unique filtered index. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Try to include the ID in the index

Comment: @mxix There's no need, since it's the clustered index

Comment: @Lamak, he wants the ID for a given <Username>. Since the IX_Person_Username does not include the ID, it won't be used. If IX_Person_Username has ID included the optimizer might choose it for the given query.

Comment: @mxix Every nonclustered index includes the key of the clustered index if there is one in the table. So, yes, `X_Person_Username` does includes the `ID`

Comment: @Lamak is correct. When I forced the use of IX_Person_UserName with a table hint, the query plan is a simple INDEX SEEK on the index. If the index did not cover the query, there would be a BOOKMARK LOOKUP as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query Optimiser doesn't necessarily choose the optimal plan.

This makes sense as it's sometimes better to run with the good plan that you've got right now rather than waste a lot of time looking for a faster one.

If you want to force your query to use that index then you can by using a TABLE HINT

```
SELECT Id FROM dbo.Person p 
WHERE UserName is not null
OPTION  (TABLE HINT(p , INDEX (IX_Person_UserName)))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

If you run both versions and Include the Actual Execution plan

```
SELECT Id FROM dbo.Person p 
WHERE UserName is not null
OPTION  (TABLE HINT(p , INDEX (IX_Person_UserName)))

SELECT Id FROM dbo.Person p 
WHERE UserName is not null
OPTION  (TABLE HINT(p , INDEX (IX_Person_Login)))
```

You'll be able to see from the query cost relative to the batch whether it actually makes any difference.

I expect you'll see

```
Query1: Query cost (relative to the batch): 50%

Query2: Query cost (relative to the batch): 50%
```

Comment: Thanks for this reminder that sometimes the optimizer will choose "good enough" rather than "best as determined by me"